# Чи можна сказати "З метою покращення"?

Tags: вживання-слів, словосполучення

Чи можна сказати «З метою покращення умов…». Стаття ["Список помилок перекладу з російської"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B7_%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97) у Вікіпедії вказує, що «Слово «мета» в українській мові передає важливе життєве завдання або ідейне спрямування людини» і пропонує замість "з метою..." вживати "щоб..." або "для...", але в мене виникають сумніви з цього приводу. Хотілося б дізнатися напевно.

Answer (score 2):

Визначення з СУМ-20

> ***[МЕТА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50710&page=1605)*** ***Те, до чого хтось прагне, чого хоче досягти;*** ціль (у 2 знач.). // Заздалегідь намічене завдання; задум (у 1 знач.).
>   Ма́ти на меті́ <Ма́ти мето́ю (ці́ллю)> див. ма́ти2; Осяга́ти /
>   осягну́ти (осягти́) [свою́] мету́ [ціль] див. осяга́ти; Ста́вити /
>   поста́вити (покла́сти) [собі́] мето́ю (за мету́) див. ста́вити.
>
> (1) ***З  мето́ю:*** **а)** (у знач. прийм. з род. в.) для
>   чого-небудь. *Вночі по тихій вулиці ходили патрулі, інколи
>   навідувалися і до Барвистих з метою перевірки мандатів* (С.
>   Чорнобривець); **б)** (у знач. спол.) для того, щоб. *Віталик іде на
>   радіовузол не з метою тепліше влаштуватися, а тому, що там треба
>   заміни, бо найближчий його друг Сашко Литвиненко з осені переходить до
>   інституту на стаціонар* (О. Гончар); *Всім дозволено говорити з
>   Генріхом з метою схилити його до покаяння* (П. Загребельний).

Отже, словосполучення *"З метою покращення..."* є абсолютно правильним.